# TinyMCE save to MySQL, then display back in TinyMCE and display on Page

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I'm integrating TinyMCE (V 4.8.2) into a web app were users can create their own webpages on a server.  We are saving everything to a MySQL Database.

What is the proper way to prepare the data to be saved into the database and then to pull it from the database later and display it?

I tried to prepare it for the save by running this code:
`$pageContent = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pageContent']);`

When I pull it from the database, I display it back in the TinyMCE Editor using this code:
`htmlspecialchars($pageContent)`

The problem is, it's adding \r\n to the display.

What is the proper way to save and display the data from TinyMCE?

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: Oy, use prepared statements with Mysqli or PDO, try not to modify the data, use something like BBCode for HTML, and use  htmlentities when displaying user input on a page to prevent XSS.  This is not a trivial thing security wise.  I suggest reading up on [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), SQLInjection and anything related to displaying user input to other users.

Comment: Thanks for the info ArtisticPhoenix. But, using htmlentities displays all the tags directly on the page; <h1>PageTitle</h1> instead of processing the tags and displaying only the data.  I need the site to display the formatting the user set while entering it.

Comment: That's the point of it, actually.  You should not allow users to put HTML in directly but instead use some kind of "template" system,  Stack overflow is a good example to make a link you don't put `<a>` tag you put `[text](url)` in, this prevents people from injecting JavaScript code into pages other users can see, which would allow them to do things like steal session cookies and log in as them etc. (XSS), when you write a post here you dont put `<strong>text</strong>` you put `**text**` and then SO converts it when it builds the page.

Comment: There are other systems then what SO uses, some use psudo tags like `[b]text[/b]` etc...  Allowing user supplied HTML is risky business.

Comment: Thank you for the input ArtisticPhoenix.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

\r\n is new line in html and it is read by tinymce.... to remove these, you will need stripslashes.

you can try

```
$pageContent = stripslashesh(str_replace('\r\n', '',$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pageContent'])));
```

only stripslashes will convert \r\n to 'rn' which will be stored as text... so str_replace can be used to remove whole \r\n..

Comment: Thanks Dr. J.  That seems to work great. But, what do I need to do to display the data back on a webpage?  I was trying htmlentities as mentioned above, but it is displaying the html tags on the page instead of the formatting.